# Proof for a recurrent sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I am currently struggling to prove the following:

Let $\left(D_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ be a complex sequence that follows: $D_{n}=p D_{n-1}+qD_{n-2}$ for every $n\geq 3$ where $p, q \in \mathbb{C}$ and $p \neq 0 \vee q \neq 0$.
For $q \neq 0$ let $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}$ be the solutions of $x^{2}=p x+q$

i. for $\lambda_{1} \neq \lambda_{2}$ show that: $D_{n}=c_{1} \lambda_{1}^{n}+c_{2} \lambda_{2}^{n}$ for $n \geq 1,$ where $c_{1}, c_{2}$ are constants determined by $D_{1}$ a $D_{2}$

ii. for $\lambda_{1}=\lambda_{2}$  show that : $D_{n}=\left(c_{1}+n c_{2}\right) \lambda_{1}^{n}$ for $n \geq 1,$ where $c_{1}, c_{2}$ are constants determined by $D_{1}$ a $D_{2}$.

I dont really know where to start with the proof or even how to understand the statement. I know that this sequence is later used to compute the determinant of tridiagonal matrix; however, I am not completly sure that this information is of any use.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, in case you didn't know, note this is basically the characteristic equation, and its roots, method to solve a [Linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\begin{pmatrix}D_n\\D_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}p&&q\\1&&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}D_{n-1}\\D_{n-2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}p&&q\\1&&0\end{pmatrix}^{n-2}\begin{pmatrix}D_{2}\\D_{1}\end{pmatrix}$